# PostgreSQL created index for double-quoted strings instead of "raw" strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

We have a table

```
CREATE TABLE public.goods
(
  ...
  namespace character varying NOT NULL,
  ...
}
```

After creation of index next way:

```
CREATE INDEX goods_namespace_idx
  ON public.goods
  USING btree
  (namespace COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

It created for double-quoted values, so in result index doesn't work as expected:

```
explain analyze select * from goods where namespace='LoadTest';
-- takes 58ms, see Seq Scan in plan

explain analyze select * from goods where namespace='"LoadTest"';
-- takes 0.047ms, Index Only Scan
```

In result it affects performance, because of sequence scan instead of index usage occurs while communicating with DB by JPQL queries via Hibernate.

So question is - could I adjust index creation to avoid using double-quoted values or should make something on application side?

Comment: Fascinating.  I don't understand how the choice of index depends on the value that being compared.

Comment: I added determination of column type to question

Comment: How many rows are in `public.goods`? Care to post a sample with which this is reproducible?

Comment: 230k of records

Comment: Why don't you post the explain output? Could it be that 'LoadTest' (without quotes) is a very common value so that using an index doesn't make sense?

Comment: Yes, @MarkusWinand was right - almost all records (229_796 of 230k) have this value. So in result postgre used seq scan and we didn't get benefits from index. Thanks!